# Как получить значение HTTP POST запроса PHP?

Tags: php, http

Есть файл, на который приходит запрос с приложения :

```
  <?php  
    mail("mailAddress", "Bla-bla", $text);
    ?>
```

Проблема состоит в том, что я не могу получить значение, присылаемого  запроса, которое должно отсылаться как текст письма.

Comment: но вы же почту только отправляете, про что вы говворите? какой запрос на файл?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php

Comment: Если это сам файл тогда предоставте первый, и докажите что действительно делаете запрос

Answer (score 0):

Используйте суперглобальную переменную `$_POST` ([документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php)).

В скрипте сделайте `var_dump($_POST);` и посмотрите что Вам приходит через HTTP POST

```
var_dump($_POST);
mail("mailAddress", "Bla-bla", $text);
```

Comment: Попробовал не работает. В приложении возникает исключение, которое показывает что ответ равен null.